# Configuración correcta para un mvc con htaccess

Tags: php, mvc, .htaccess

Estoy realizando una configuración del archivo .htaccess para poder crear un página web con la arquitectura o patrón mvc en php pero no consigo que dicha configuración me redirija las peticiones a https.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Activar rewrite 
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
Header unset "X-Powered-By"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

ErrorDocument 404 https://{direccion_url_pagina_web}/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2

</IfModule>
```

Cualquier mejora significativa o opinión crítica constructiva es bienvenida, muchas gracias por adelantado por la ayuda que me podáis brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique estas directivas de configuración si su archivo oculto .htaccess está en la raíz principal:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/method/param$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Reescribirá [www.example.com/index.php/](http://www.example.com/index.php/) $ var / method / param en [www.example.com/index.php?url=](http://www.example.com/index.php?url=) $ var pero asegúrese de que su archivo .htaccess esté en la raíz principal.

Prueba este:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```